# Issue using RazorEngine with a dynamic model composed using JSON.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Json.net to convert a json string into a dynamic.  When I use this dynamic as a model for a Razor template, I am getting an error...

> Unable to compile template. 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not
>   contain a definition  for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name'
>   accepting a first argument of type  'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

If I just use a simple anonymous object as the model, it works fine.

Here is the problem displayed in a simple console app where I used NuGet to pull in two libraries...Newtonsoft JSON and RazorEngine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // template used for generation
            var template = "<div>Hello @Model.Name</div>";

            // create model
            dynamic model = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
            model.Name = "Foo";

            // this works just fine
            RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(template, model);

            // convert model to string
            var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

            // regenerate model
            model = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);

            // this prints 'Foo' to the console just fine so the model is valid!
            string name = model.Name;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);

            // this throws the error above!
            RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(template, model);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with the problem here?

Comment: Did you try doing : var template = "<div>Hello @(Convert.ToString(Model.Name))</div>";

Comment: I found an alternative solution that does the same thing I was trying to do with json.net (http://bit.ly/KHAGVs).  That has the final solution, but it all started with this blog post (http://bit.ly/KHALsd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly pass the `JObjects` into the `RazorEngine` because whenever you assign a value to the `JObject` they are stored as type `JValue`. When you try to retrieve the assigned value also you will get a `JValue` not the assigned one.

Ex.

```
dynamic person = new JObject();
person.Name = "Vijay";

Console.WriteLine(person.Name.GetType());

==> NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JValue
```

Comment: This is the answer to my question regarding using a JObject, but I found an alternative solution that I outlined in a comment above.